# Update href in Asp.NET Project using Regular expressions and VS Replace option

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2013

I have project on Asp.NET Web Forms.

I need to update hrefs on Views. This hrefs is for Downloading, so on click user are able to save document, in my case `.pdf` files. So i need to change href-Links just for target pdf-files

Example : Now href is in next format:

```
href="/about/news/downloads/Ingram%20Announcement_5.31.07.pdf"
```

What is needed : Add

```
<%=MyProject.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Content%>
```

instead of first `/` in href link (possible href link hasn't `/` as first symbol).

Expected result is:

```
href="<%=MyProject.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Content%>
    about/news/downloads/Ingram%20Announcement_5.31.07.pdf"
```

How can i make this update using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and Regex?

Work in VS 2013

Comment: Do you want to replace the targets programatically or just once in the editor?

Comment: @khlr, just using Find/Replace option in VS 2012

Comment: can you expand on the format of the link a bit more - is it any `href`, anything inside "about/news" ...?

Comment: @Rhumborl, href-link is target on another repository ( we moved static content into different repository to make project smaller). I need to change links for pdf-files now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match any href ending in ".pdf".

**Regex:** `href\=\"/?([^"]+\.pdf)\"`.

Note this will match the optional `/` but not capture it. Then it finds at least 1 character which is not a quote to close the `href` and ends with `.pdf"`. The path without the leading `/` and filename are then stored in match position $1

**Replacement:** `href="<%=MyProject.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Content%>$1"`

If you want to match other extensions in addition to pdfs, you can just add an OR clause `|` to the regex. For example `href\=\"/?([^"]+\.(pdf|jpg))\"` will match pdfs and jpgs. The replacement does not need to change

Comment: one more question : if href contains link to some url not from my projects, how can i modify regex?

Comment: If you mean ignore stuff starting with `http`, you would need to use a [negative-lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) `(?!xxx)`. Something like `href\=\"(?!http)/?([^"]+\.pdf)\"`

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and enter `href="/` into the *search term* and `href="<%=MyProject.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Content%>` into the *replacement term*.

Comment: it will be wrong as i also has href links that i don't want to change. Currently i need to change hrefs that target to pdf-files